# python run executable in python script

Tags: python, binary, subprocess, executable

I wanna call an mpi program inside my python script, the mpi program is an executable in the path "/scratch2/yuhengd/plda+/infer"

while I can run the "infer" directly from linux command line (without using sh or ./ before the command "/scratch2/yuhengd/plda+/infer"), I can not use a subprocess in python script to call it, it doesn't give any error and it doesnt' execute it either. The python code is here:

```
infer_command = "/scratch2/yuhengd/plda+/infer --alpha 0.1 --beta 0.01 --... /scratch2/yuhengd/data/commoncrawl/LDA/local_models/"+forumid+"-commoncrawl-excludeunif-model --total_iterations 500 --burn_in_iterations 250"

print infer_command
exit_status = subprocess.call(infer_command, shell=True)
if exit_status is 1:
    print (forumid + " infer failed")
```

What should I do to make this work? thanks.

Update::
I used the following code to test the subprocess call:

import subprocess

```
command = "/scratch2/yuhengd/plda+/infer --alpha 0.1 --beta 0.01 --inference_data_file ... /scratch2/yuhengd/data/commoncrawl/LDA/local_models/e70-commoncrawl-excludeunif-model --total_iterations 500 --burn_in_iterations 250"

exit_status = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
if exit_status == 1:
    print command + "failed"
```

It doesn't show any error message but didn't execute the program either.

Comment: What's the output traceback?

Comment: What about error codes other than 1? Print all exit statuses and see if its something like 255.

Comment: Compare using `==` not `is`

Comment: The output doesn't show any error messages. It just didn't execute the command.

Comment: I used the following code for testing the subprocess call: